# Obtaining Yesterday In Bash

Tags: bash

Is there an easier way to calculate yesterday in Bash? This code (used for incremental tars)

```
mod_time=""

if [ ! -z ${1} ]; then
    if [ "${1}" = "i" ]; then

        this_month=`date +%m`

        this_year=`date +%y`

        last_day=`date +%d`

        # Subtract one from today's day, to get yesterday.

        if [ "${last_day:0:1}" = "0" ]; then
            if [ "${last_day:1:1}" > "1" ]; then
                last_day=$[$((${last_day:1:1})) - 1]
            fi
        else
            last_day=$[$(($last_day)) - 1]
        fi

        # zero pad if necessary

        if [ 10 -gt $last_day ]; then
            last_day="0$last_day"
        fi

        mod_time=" --newer-mtime $this_month/$last_day/$this_year "
    fi
fi
```

has a couple of problems like calculating day 0, and also not doing the right thing at the end of the month. I don't want to build in leap year calculations, and am wondering if there's an easy way to do this in Bash. If not, I'll use Clojure or Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

```
 date -d "yesterday" +%Y%m%d
```

return

```
 20120202
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm missing your point, but why not:

```
$ date -d yesterday
Wed Feb  1 11:53:12 EST 2012
```

(might be a GNU extension so no promises you'll have it). If you do, I'd say it's easier :).

Answer (score 2):

```
date -d yesterday
```

Answer (score 2):

Well for me this seems a bit shorter:

```
date --date "1 day ago"
```